# Return Data - Java

Tags: java, spring

I have a front end that gives me a query and a type.

The types are JSON and XML. How can I create and send the download file to the ajax post?

```
@RestController
public class RestCtrl {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@GetMapping("/getData")
List<Map<String, Object>> getData(@RequestParam String type, @RequestParam String query) {
    System.out.println(type + " " + query);
    List<Map<String, Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
    if(type.equals("JSON")) {

    }
    else if (type.equals("XML")){

    }
}
}
```

Basically the XML would have the column names in <> for example `<TITLE>This is a title</TITLE>` I this is is SOAP, right?

Something like this: https://flowgear-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/XML-vs-JSON1.png

Edit:nothing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Spring Web documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces

> You can narrow the request mapping based on the Accept request header
>   and the list of content types that a controller method produces.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes

> You can narrow the request mapping based on the Content-Type of the
>   request.

**Request**

Client application can control `POST` request data mime format (XML, JSON) using `Content-Type` HTTP header. For example:

1. `Content-Type: application/json` will define that request data is provided in the JSON format
2. `Content-Type: text/xml` will define that request data is provided in the XML format

The server-side application can control what mime format it can process using `consumes` attribute of the @PostMapping annotation:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/pets", consumes = "application/json")
public void addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet) {
    // ...
}
```

If 'Content-Type' header value doesn't match the consumer attribute value, Spring will produce an exception that it can process input data.

**Response**

Client application can control response data mime format (XML, JSON) using `Accept` HTTP header. For example:

1. `Accept: application/json` will define that the client can accept data is provided in the JSON format
2. `Accept: text/xml` will define that the client can accept data in the XML format

The server-side application can control what mime format it can process using `produces` attribute of the @RequestMapping, @GetMapping and other annotations:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/pets/{petId}", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public Pet getPet(@PathVariable String petId) {
    // ...
}
```

If 'Accept' header value doesn't match the produces attribute value, Spring will produce an exception that it can process input data.

Spring defined useful constants for the widely used mime-types:

```
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

For the full list of values, check documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html

`consumes` and `produces` are multi-valued attributes. Multiple values can be specified as a list:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/pets/{petId}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the returned media type, spring will handle that for you, you need to add 'produces' to your rest endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value="getData", method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
List<Map<String, Object>> getData(@RequestParam String type, @RequestParam String query) {
```

you may need to add jackson dataformat for an implicit POJO to XML mapping

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That can help but it's incomplete. I need to execute the query and the file needs to be downloded from the frontend